# How to get the value from Laravel Collection

Tags: laravel

I have a Model called OfficeHours which as various attributes and the model User belongsTo OfficeHours. I am trying to fetch a particular element from a collection but am getting blank in blade.

```
  public function office_hours() {
        return $this->hasMany(OfficeHours::class);
    } 
  public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

In Blade when i do the following:

```
{{$logged_in_user->office_hours->where('dow',2)}}
```

it works and gets me the following collection:

```
{"2":{"id":3,"user_id":4,"dow":2,"fromtime":"07:00:00","totime":"16:00:00","created_at":"2019-01-31 14:48:32","updated_at":null}}
```

now how i do i get the elements of that collection?

i tried

```
{{$logged_in_user->office_hours->where('dow',2)->get('fromtime')}}
```

but it gives me blank

How do i access the elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To preface, you shouldn't be doing that kind of logic in the `view` file, this is what controllers are for. You'd be able to do `$fromtime = ...;` and pass that to the view via `return view(...)->with(["fromtime" => $fromtime]);`

But, that being said, you should be able to do

```
{{ $logged_in_user->office_hours->where("dow", 2)->first()->fromtime }}
```

Note you're gonna get an error if `->where("dow", 2)` doesn't return a `Collection`, as `null` doesn't have a `->first()` method on it.